# Tax ID/social security number After leaving USA

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security

I am currently a Canadian working in the US. I have a working visa so I also have a social security/tax id.

My question is when I leave the country in the future what happens to my social security number?

I currently have a couple of investment accounts that’s registered only because I have a address and SSN(only allow us based residence register). I was wondering what happens to these once I leave the Country and not work here anymore?

Note that once I leave the country I don’t owe any tax to US because I am not a citizen.

Curious if anyone encountered such situation before.

Thanks

Comment: Checking the double tax avoidance treaty between US and Canada is absolutely necessary in this case - the regulations can give you some advantage in terms withholding tax being actually lower that tax in US. In addition you may need to change the way you pay tax in Canada. All the details are in the treaty. And beware some tax advisors who sometimes do not know what they speak about and do not even check while charging high rates. At least that's may personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSN is yours for life.

Unless you close down your investment accounts before (or after) you leave the US, any income (interest, dividends, capital gains, etc) that is generated in the investment accounts is nonetheless taxable income in the US to you even though you are no longer residing in the US. Many countries have tax treaties or double-taxation avoidance agreements (DTAA) with the US, but these typically say things like each country agrees not to tax income generated in the other country, or each country agrees to give a credit on the taxpayer's tax return for the income tax paid to the other country, which effectively means that the taxpayer pays the higher of the taxes imposed by the two countries. Canada has a especially close relationship to the US, and so the rules might be a modification of the above, and of course, there will be another country that will be involved if the OP moves to another country (different from Canada and the US) upon leaving the US.

Comment: Dividends mostly yes (there are some exceptions), **interest** mostly yes in general but **not for Canada**, **capital gains no** (unless on real estate, timber, coal, iron ore, or certain patents). See pub 519 and treaty table 1. (I advise OP, and all aliens involved in activity possibly subject to US tax, to see pub 519.)